# Visual Studio Shortcut for showing list of tabs

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I don't know if there is a better way to ask this.  But, I mean to open the small down arrow which shows the list of tabs (see following) using a keyboard shortcut

[image: list of files currently opened]

Comment: think Ctrl-Tab will show you the list of open files.

Comment: Know that, but curious about "that" menu if it could be opened using a shortcut

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Command that you are looking for is `Window.ShowEzMDIFileList`, it can be accessed(*at least on my machine*) by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>

[image]

Comment: On my machine <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> flips the display upside down !

Comment: @NickEdwards That's why the caveat, you can look at the keys that are assigned to te command that I gave to figure out how it is setup on yours.